# phpMyAdmin: Only show the active database, don't show a database tree in the left panel

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed a new version of XAMPP (1.8.2) with the phpMyAdmin version 4.1.12. I noticed that in phpMyAdmin the left panel where you can browse through databases and tables has changed.
Now, it always shows a database tree. I just want to see the tables of the active database, that I have selected. Is that somehow possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I've got the exact same question.. With a lot of databases it's very annoying the sidebar keeps showing all the databases..

Comment: With the version 4.4 of phpMyAdmin (soon to be released I think), one will be able to revert back to old-style navigation panel with a database selector and only current database tables being displayed.
For switching this behavior, set configuration option $cfg['ShowDatabasesNavigationAsTree'] to 'false'.